Settters and getters are not recoginzed by Intellij
Annotation processing is enabled and the Lombok entry is present in the pom.xml, but I'm getting an error  that setAttribute method is not working  . The corresponding screenshots have been attached.
Below is the error message:
User.java

@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(length = 30)
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 30, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(length = 15, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String phoneNo;

    private String address;



    private String password;
    private String authority;


java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setAuthority(java.lang.String)
  location: variable user of type com.example.UserService.model.User

Annotation Processing
Below is the parent pom.xml
<build>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
             <annotationProcessorPaths>
                <path>
                   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                </path>
             </annotationProcessorPaths>
          </configuration>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
             <excludes>
                <exclude>
                   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                </exclude>
             </excludes>
          </configuration>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

